# Run unit tests when building app (Android)

Tags: java, android, unit-testing, testing, junit

We have some JUnit tests in our project. Is there a way to have the tests run whenever we build the app (locally)? We have a CI server, but it would be great to get confirmation whenever we run the app locally that the tests have failed, rather than having to wait for CI or manually select the option to run the tests.

Answer (score 0):

You can write gradle or ant script to build Android app and execute Junits, you can also generate Code coverage reports.

I have used ant for this, and i am successfully able to do it.

1.You need to create a `build.xml` in your app dir:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project name="YourAppName" default="help">
    <property file="local.properties" />
    <property file="build.properties" />
    <property file="ant.properties" />
    <property environment="env" />
    <condition property="sdk.dir" value="${env.ANDROID_HOME}">
        <isset property="env.ANDROID_HOME" />
    </condition>
    <loadproperties srcFile="project.properties" />
    <fail
            message="sdk.dir is missing. Make sure to generate local.properties using 'android update project' or to inject it through the ANDROID_HOME environment variable."
            unless="sdk.dir"
    />
    <import file="custom_rules.xml" optional="true" />
    <import file="${sdk.dir}/tools/ant/build.xml" />
</project>
```

2.You need to create a `custom_rules.xml` in your app dir:

```
<project xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">

  <property name="build.type" value="build" />
  <import file="buildnumber.xml"/>
  <import file="unittest.xml"/>
  <property name="src.to.unittest.dir.1" value="src" />
  <property name="src.to.unittest.dir.2" value="gen" />
  <path id="src.to.unittest.path">
    <pathelement path="${src.to.unittest.dir.1}"/>
    <pathelement path="${src.to.unittest.dir.2}"/>
  </path>

  <path id="src.of.unittests.path">
    <pathelement path="unittests"/>
    <pathelement path="functests"/>
  </path>

  <target name="dev-default">

  </target>

  <target name="-package-resources" depends="-crunch">
        <echo>env package suffix: ${env.target.package} </echo>
        <!-- only package resources if *not* a library project -->
        <do-only-if-not-library elseText="Library project: do not package resources..." >
            <aapt executable="${aapt}"
                    manifestPackage="com.yourpackage${env.target.package}"
                    command="package"
                    versioncode="${version.code}"
                    versionname="${version.name}"
                    debug="${build.is.packaging.debug}"
                    manifest="${out.manifest.abs.file}"
                    assets="${asset.absolute.dir}"
                    androidjar="${project.target.android.jar}"
                    apkfolder="${out.absolute.dir}"
                    nocrunch="${build.packaging.nocrunch}"
                    resourcefilename="${resource.package.file.name}"
                    resourcefilter="${aapt.resource.filter}"
                    libraryResFolderPathRefid="project.library.res.folder.path"
                    libraryPackagesRefid="project.library.packages"
                    libraryRFileRefid="project.library.bin.r.file.path"
                    previousBuildType="${build.last.target}"
                    buildType="${build.target}"
                    ignoreAssets="${aapt.ignore.assets}">
                <res path="${out.res.absolute.dir}" />
                <res path="${resource.absolute.dir}" />
            </aapt>
        </do-only-if-not-library>
    </target>
</project>
```

3.You need to create a `unittest.xml` in you app dir:

```
<project xmlns:jacoco="antlib:org.jacoco.ant">

  <!-- IMPORTANT: your project and all library dependencies must be built first
       then you can run the cobertura-generate-reports task
  -->

  <!-- import this file from your Android project custom_rules.xml 

       define these properties:
        src.to.unittest.dir.1 - required
        src.to.unittest.dir.2 - optional
        src.to.unittest.dir.3 - optional
        src.to.unittest.dir.4 - optional
          these properties specify the source directories that contain the code that
          you want to test.

       commonandroid.classes
         override this if common is not a sibling of your project dir

       and these paths:
        src.to.unittest.path  - required
          use the dir.1 - dir.4 properties above to define
          this path specifies the code under test that will be built

        src.of.unittests.path - required
          this path species the unit test code that will be built


  -->

  <property name="shared.externals.dir" value="path/to/android/externals/libs"/>
<!--
  <property name="commonandroid.classes" value="../common/bin/classes" />
-->
  <property name="coverage.report.format" value="xml"/>
  <property name="cobertura.excludes" value="**/*Tests*"/>

  <path id="classpath.junit">
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/junit/4.12" id="fileset.junit">
      <include name="junit-4.12.jar"/>
      <include name="hamcrest-core-1.3.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="classpath.jmockit">
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/jmockit/1.20" id="fileset.jmockit">
      <include name="jmockit.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="classpath.jmockit.coverage">
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/jmockit/1.20" id="fileset.jmockit.coverage">
      <include name="jmockit-coverage.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
  <path id="classpath.robolectric">
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/robolectric/3.1" id="fileset.robolectric">
      <include name="*.jar"/>
    </fileset>
<!--
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/robolectric/2.4" id="fileset.robolectric">
      <include name="robolectric-2.4-jar-with-dependencies.jar"/>
       <include name="robolectric-2.4-sources.jar"/>
    </fileset>
-->
  </path>

<!--
  <path id="classpath.logback">
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/logback/1.1.2" id="fileset.logback">
      <include name="logback-classic-1.1.2.jar"/>
      <include name="logback-core-1.1.2.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>
-->

  <path id="classpath.slf4j">
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/slf4j/1.7.13" id="fileset.slf4j">
      <include name="slf4j-api-1.7.13.jar"/>
      <include name="slf4j-jdk14-1.7.13.jar"/>
      <include name="slf4j-log4j12-1.7.13.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="classpath.cobertura2">
    <fileset dir="${shared.externals.dir}/cobertura/2.1.1" id="fileset.cobertura2">
      <include name="asm-*.jar"/>
      <include name="cobertura*.jar"/>
      <include name="oro-2.0.8.jar"/>
      <include name="commons-lang3*.jar"/>
      <include name="logback*.jar" />
    </fileset>
    <path refid="classpath.slf4j" />
<!--
    <path refid="classpath.logback" />
-->
    <pathelement location="."/>
  </path>

  <path id="classpath.android">
    <fileset dir="${sdk.dir}/platforms/${target}" id="fileset.android">
      <include name="android.jar"/>
    </fileset>
  </path>

  <path id="auxClassesPath">
    <pathelement location="${commonandroid.classes}"/>
    <path refid="classpath.android"/>
  </path>

  <taskdef classpathref="classpath.cobertura2" resource="tasks.properties"/>

  <taskdef uri="antlib:org.jacoco.ant" resource="org/jacoco/ant/antlib.xml">
      <classpath path="${shared.externals.dir}/jacoco/0.7.8/jacocoant.jar"/>
  </taskdef>

  <property name="reports" location="unittest-results"/>
  <property name="jacoco.coverage.data" location="${reports}/jacoco.exec"/>
  <property name="classes.unittest.dir" location="${reports}/classes"/>
  <property name="cobertura.dir" location="${reports}/cobertura"/>
  <property name="cobertura.build" location="${cobertura.dir}/build"/>
  <property name="cobertura.dist" location="${cobertura.dir}/dist"/>
  <property name="cobertura.instr" location="${cobertura.dir}/instr"/>
  <property name="cobertura.reportsrc" location="${cobertura.dir}/reportsrc"/>
  <property name="cobertura.jar" value="cobertura-unittests.jar"/>
  <property name="src.unittests.dir" value="unittests"/>


  <target name="clean.unittest">
    <delete dir="${reports}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="init.unittest" depends="clean.unittest">
    <mkdir dir="${classes.unittest.dir}"/>
    <property name="dont.do.deps" value="true"/>
  </target>

  <target name="compile.unittest.pathsetup">
    <path id="project.javac.classpath">
      <path refid="project.all.jars.path" />
      <path refid="tested.project.classpath" />
      <path refid="classpath.robolectric"/>
      <path refid="classpath.jmockit"/>
      <path refid="classpath.junit"/>
      <path refid="classpath.android"/>
    </path>
  </target>


  <target name="compile.unittest" depends="init.unittest, -build-setup, compile.unittest.pathsetup">

    <javac encoding="${java.encoding}"
           source="${java.source}" target="${java.target}"
           debug="true" extdirs="" includeantruntime="false"
           destdir="${classes.unittest.dir}"
           bootclasspathref="project.target.class.path"
           verbose="${verbose}"
           classpathref="project.javac.classpath"
           fork="${need.javac.fork}">
      <src refid="src.to.unittest.path"/>
      <src refid="src.of.unittests.path"/>
      <compilerarg line="${java.compilerargs}" />
    </javac>

    <copy todir="${classes.unittest.dir}" failonerror="true" overwrite="true" verbose="true">
      <fileset dir="functests" includes="**/*.xml" />
  </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="jar.unittest" depends="compile.unittest">
  </target>

  <target name="cobertura-clean" depends="jar.unittest">
    <delete dir="${cobertura.dir}"/>
    <delete dir="${cobertura.build}"/>
    <delete dir="${cobertura.dist}"/>
    <delete dir="${cobertura.instr}"/>
    <delete dir="${cobertura.reportsrc}"/>
    <delete>
      <fileset dir="${reports}" includes="TEST*.xml"/>
    </delete>
  </target>

  <target name="cobertura-init" depends="cobertura-clean">
    <mkdir dir="${cobertura.dir}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${cobertura.build}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${cobertura.dist}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${cobertura.instr}"/>
    <mkdir dir="${cobertura.reportsrc}"/>
  </target>

  <target name="cobertura-instrument" depends="cobertura-init">
    <jar destfile="${cobertura.dist}/${cobertura.jar}" update="true">
      <fileset dir="${classes.unittest.dir}">
        <exclude name="${cobertura.excludes}"/>
      </fileset>
    </jar>

    <cobertura-instrument todir="${cobertura.instr}" datafile="${cobertura.dir}/cobertura.ser">
      <fileset dir="${cobertura.dist}">
        <include name="${cobertura.jar}"/>
      </fileset>
      <auxClasspath refid="auxClassesPath"/>
    </cobertura-instrument>
  </target>

  <target name="cobertura-unit-test" depends="cobertura-instrument">
    <echo>project.javac.classpath = ${toString:project.javac.classpath}</echo>
    <condition property="junit.dir" value="${user.dir}/${basedir}" else=".">
      <isset property="${basedir}"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="Running JUnit tests in : ${junit.dir}"/>
    <junit dir="${junit.dir}"
           showoutput="no"
           printsummary="on"
           haltonfailure="no"
           haltonerror="no"
           failureproperty="junit.failure"
           fork="true"
           forkmode="perTest"
           maxmemory="512m">
      <classpath>
        <fileset dir="${cobertura.instr}">
          <include name="${cobertura.jar}"/>
        </fileset>
        <pathelement location="${classes.unittest.dir}"/>
        <path refid="classpath.cobertura2"/>
        <path refid="project.javac.classpath"/>
      </classpath>
      <jvmarg value="-XX:-UseSplitVerifier"/>
      <formatter type="xml"/>
      <sysproperty key="net.sourceforge.cobertura.datafile" file="${cobertura.dir}/cobertura.ser"/>
      <batchtest todir="${reports}">
        <fileset dir="${classes.unittest.dir}">
          <include name="**/*MainActivity*Tests.class"/>
          <include name="**/*FormActivity*Tests.class"/>
<!--
          <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
          <include name="**/*Tests.class"/>
-->
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>

    <junitreport todir="${reports}">
      <fileset dir="${reports}">
        <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
      </fileset>
      <report format="frames" todir="${reports}/junit"/>
    </junitreport>

    <!-- The tests are configured to continue if there is a failure so we can check for more than one-->
    <!-- failure.  So we check if there was at least one failure, if so, we'll fail the build.-->
    <fail message="One or more unit tests failed" if="junit.failure"/>
  </target>

  <target name="report-copy-all-source-files">
    <copy todir="${cobertura.reportsrc}" failonerror="false">
      <fileset dir="${src.to.unittest.dir.1}" />
      <fileset dir="${src.to.unittest.dir.2}" />
      <fileset dir="${src.to.unittest.dir.3}" />
      <fileset dir="${src.to.unittest.dir.4}" />
    </copy>
  </target>

  <target name="cobertura-generate-reports" depends="cobertura-unit-test, report-copy-all-source-files">
    <cobertura-report destdir="${cobertura.dir}"
                      format="${coverage.report.format}"
                      datafile="${cobertura.dir}/cobertura.ser" srcdir="${cobertura.reportsrc}">
    </cobertura-report>
  </target>

  <target name="env-unittests">
    <property name="env.target.package" value="" />
    <property name="env.app.name" value="app_name" />
  </target>

  <target name="build-for-test" depends="env-unittests, clean, debug"/>

  <target name="build-and-test">
    <antcall target="build-for-test"/>
    <antcall target="jacoco-unit-test"/>
    <antcall target="jacoco-report"/>
    <antcall target="jacoco-check-coverage"/>
  </target>

   <target name="test">
    <antcall target="jacoco-unit-test"/>
    <antcall target="jacoco-check-coverage"/>
  </target>

  <target name="jacoco-unit-test" depends="compile.unittest, copy-test-res">
    <echo>project.javac.classpath = ${toString:project.javac.classpath}</echo>
    <condition property="junit.dir" value="${user.dir}/${basedir}" else=".">
      <isset property="${basedir}"/>
    </condition>
    <echo message="Running JUnit tests in : ${junit.dir}"/>
    <jacoco:coverage inclnolocationclasses="true" destfile="${jacoco.coverage.data}">
    <junit dir="${junit.dir}"
           showoutput="no"
           printsummary="on"
           haltonfailure="no"
           haltonerror="no"
           failureproperty="junit.failure"
           fork="true"
           forkmode="once"
           maxmemory="1024m">
      <classpath>
        <pathelement location="${classes.unittest.dir}"/>
        <path refid="project.javac.classpath"/>
      </classpath>
      <formatter type="xml"/>
      <batchtest todir="${reports}">
        <fileset dir="${classes.unittest.dir}">
<!--
          <include name="**/*MainActivity*Tests.class"/>
          <include name="**/*FormActivity*Tests.class"/>
-->
          <include name="**/*Test.class"/>
          <include name="**/*Tests.class"/>
        </fileset>
      </batchtest>
    </junit>
    </jacoco:coverage>

    <junitreport todir="${reports}">
      <fileset dir="${reports}">
        <include name="TEST-*.xml"/>
      </fileset>
      <report format="frames" todir="${reports}/junit"/>
    </junitreport>

    <!-- The tests are configured to continue if there is a failure so we can check for more than one-->
    <!-- failure.  So we check if there was at least one failure, if so, we'll fail the build.-->
    <fail message="One or more unit tests failed" if="junit.failure"/>
  </target>
</project>
```

4. You need to create a `buildnumber.xml` in you app dir: